# Can I use a split in replace?

Tags: jquery, html, split

I have some html that looks like this:

```
<div id=lw>
    <div class=lw>
        <ul id=lwe>
            <li class=lwe>
                <div class=lwn> <span class=lwn0>Jul 1 - Sep 6 </span>
```

I only care about the "Jul" part of the contents of that `span`. I am trying to see that the span has "Jul", then replace that to say "July".

I'm trying to shave off that " - Sep 6" by using `split()` on that span class, and replacing the old html text with the new. This is my code:

```
var a = $(".lwn0").text();
var rep = $(".lwn0").html().replace(a, a.split(' - ')[0]);
    $(".lwn0").html(rep);
```

That's not working. I'm not really sure why. **Is it legal to use `split()` inside of `replace()`?**

Comment: Seems to work fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/a6t3aadw/).

Comment: @Imgonzalves - interesting. I had mine in a JSFiddle as well but it wasn't working.. Oh well - Felipe Skinner's answer seems to work fine for me anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using replace on the html instead of the text.

This should work:

```
var rep = a.replace(a, a.split(' - ')[0]);
```

Comment: Cannot believe I didn't see that. +1 - will accept when it allows me.

Comment: it happens a lot to me :)